# Cairo + grid: grouped shapes in Cairo devices

Tags: r, cairo, r-grid

`grid` allows you to create several primitives of one kind by supplying multiple parameters to the primitive's drawing function. However, this doesn't seem work on **Cairo** devices, which appear to only receive the first of the series of primitives. Does anyone know of a workaround for this or care to comment on the issue?

```
library(grid)
grid.circle(r=1:3/10) # draw three circles of radii .1, .2, and .3
```

[image]

```
library(Cairo)
CairoPNG()
grid.circle(r=1:3/10)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Of course, three separate calls to `grid.circle` will generate the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When plotting primitives in **Cairo**, there is an assumed white fill. Setting the fill parameter to `NA` resolves this.

```
CairoPNG()
grid.circle(r=1:3/10, gp=gpar(fill=NA))
dev.off()
```